# Thin::RestartTimeout when using onebyone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, capistrano, thin

The onebyone feature of Thin seems cool, but it's causing my deploys to fail.

```
** [out :: 97.107.141.165] Stopping server on 127.0.0.1:3000 ...
** [out :: 97.107.141.165] Sending QUIT signal to process 2515 ...
** [out :: 97.107.141.165] >> Exiting!
** [out :: 97.107.141.165] Starting server on 127.0.0.1:3000 ...
** [out :: 97.107.141.165] Waiting for server to start ...
** [out :: 97.107.141.165] /home/deploy/iamthewalrus/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/controllers/cluster.rb:106:in `block in wait_until_server_started': The server didn't start in time. Please look at server's log file for more information, or set the value of 'wait' in your config file to be higher (defaults: 30). (Thin::RestartTimeout)
```

I've tried changing the wait time to 60 seconds, but that doesn't solve the problem.  In fact, the server on port 3000 actually does come back up, it's just that Thin doesn't seem to think so.

Any thoughts?

```
---
chdir: /home/deploy/iamthewalrus/current
environment: production
address: 127.0.0.1
port: 3000
timeout: 30
log: log/thin.log
pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid
max_conns: 1024
max_persistent_conns: 512
require: []
wait: 30
servers: 3
daemonize: true
onebyone: true
```

Comment: For me changing the wait time to 45 seconds did work, in a raspberry. Use `htop` to check the CPU use and thin process memory size, it should have time to reach its normal memory size before your wait time expires for this error not to occur.